# is there a rationale as to why MIPS uses 2 pointers to reference a program argument?

Tags: memory-management, stack, arguments, mips

I've been using the MARS(4.5v) IDE to learn more about MIPS.

- I noticed that when using program arguments — register $a1 will
  contain a value that is a memory address.
- That 1st memory address will have a 2nd memory address stored at its
  location.
- That 2nd memory address will be the first character of the program
  argument and every subsequent address will contain the next character
  until the null terminating character is reached indicating the end of
  that argument.

Architecturally, is there a reason why that 1st address is necessary? I feel as if there is a reason as to why this must happen for memory management purposes but I cannot quite connect the dots. The 2nd address always starts at the last address within the range of the stack memory but the 1st address appears to be a random address within the stack range.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's an array of strings, so that's two dimensions before you get to characters.